# "Open With" (lsregister) to show apps on system disk (specific disk)

Tags: macos, spotlight

I have a Mac pro with 4 disks, one is for the system (D1)

"Open With" takes long time sometimes, and sometimes it shows me apps on other disks (old, backup, other test apps), how I can make OS X to show me only apps on D1 and not on the rest (D2, D3, D4) when using "Open With"?

I do not want to exclude the non-system disks from Spotlight (for searching documents and "apps") I just want to exclude them from "Open With"!

I did see solutions like

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -seed -r -f -v -domain local -domain user -domain system
```

or something like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/348930/how-to-prevent-applications-on-an-external-hard-drive-from-showing-up-in-the-op) , but none suite my need!

Comment: If you're not willing to make some Spotlight Search exclusions then I do not believe there is another way. You do not need to exclude the whole drive, just the Folders containing the apps (as step 1) and follow then follow the other steps in the linked page in your question.